# TGraphicControl Equivalent to FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I need to create an FMX component, formerly I used TGraphicControl but the architecture has changed a lot for FMX. The component to create is an array, where I determine pixel size being height and width, and the number of pixels per row and column, for example, a 30 row by 45 column array with 15x15 pixel frames each. I would do this in VCL with TGraphicControl, and now in FMX, what is the equivalent?

Comment: I would suggest `TShape`

Comment: Or `TPaintBox`.  Or just derive from `TControl` directly, like `TShape`, `TPaintBox`, `TImage`, etc do.